# Which storage (weak or strong) for the elements underneath the "main" View in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, weak-references, strong-references

After reading really many books and docs on iOS programming I am still confused - which Storage type (weak or strong) to select, when control dragging from a UI element underneath the "main" View? (and by "main" *I think* I mean the UIView assigned to the `view` property of the ViewController):

[image]

For example I'm trying to recreate the example [iOS SDK: Working with NSUserDefaults](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/) by Mr. Jeroen van Rijn - **with Xcode 5.0.2 and iOS7**.

[image]

His code is lacking the weak/strong specifiers and I wonder, which would be correct here?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ContactViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *contactImageView;
    IBOutlet UITextField *firstNameTextField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *lastNameTextField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *ageTextField;
}
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: IBOutlets should be defined as weak, as they will be retained by the View that creates them. Your ViewController just wants the reference and doesn't need to retain them again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that view is already retained by the view that creates them (the one you set in the interface builder) you don't need to retain them again, so you have to choose *weak*, not *strong*.

Comment: Thanks, too bad Xcode 5 suggests "strong" when I control drag in assistant mode.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need outlet for the view in this example. You can access it like:

```
self.view
```

in your ContactViewController or like:

```
ContactViewController *contact = [[ContactViewController alloc] init];
contact.view
```

from other view controller.
However for your outlets you should you weak.